# Regex in Notepad++ to get the resource keys

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need help to come up with a regular expression for cleaning the aspx page entries.

```
....
Line 24: <asp:Button ID="id1" runat="server" meta:resourceKey="ButtonTxt"/>
Line 35: <asp:Label ID="id2" runat="server" meta:resourceKey="Name"></asp:Label>
Line 47: <asp:Label ID="id3" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="Other_Name"></asp:Label>
....
```

How do I write the regular expression to extract only `meta:resourceKey="ButtonTxt"`, `meta:resourceKey="Name"`, `meta:resourcekey="Other_Name"` and so on. Basically I need to extract only the `meta:resourcekey="xxxx"` strings.

I tried `.*?(meta:.*?").*` but this gets only till the first `"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used the `?` qualifier to turn the `*`-quantifier before the `"` non-greedy (or "lazy"). This means it will match as little as possible with the given pattern. That is why this quantifier matches only until the first `"`. The rest is covered by the `.*` that follows your match group.

If you remove the `?` the `*`-quantifier matches greedy (which is the default behavior). A greedy quantifier will match as much as possible, which in your case is the second `"`.

You can see the difference here: https://regex101.com/r/IgA15K/1

And there is some documentation on the concept: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/quantifiers-in-regular-expressions#greedy-and-lazy-quantifiers

Comment: Thanks Manuel !! This was exactly what I wanted. Let me understand quantor  and greedy concepts as well.

Comment: I am glad you find my answer helpful. :) In this case you can mark it as the accepted answer.